# Is this LINQ query incorrect?

Tags: c#, linq

So what I'm doing is a query to get Absences from an employee (trough his ID) of a certain year (2015 in this case).

[image]

This is the DB Model, and these are the Classes:

```
[Serializable] 
public class Absence
{
    public Int32 IDAbsence;
    public Int32 IDEmployee;
    public Int32 Period;
    public DateTime BeginDate;
    public DateTime? EndDate;
    public AbsenceType AbsenceType;
    public AbsenceStatus AbsenceStatus;
    public List<Justification> Justifications;
    public List<Notification> Notifications;

    public Absence() { }

    public Absence(Int32 IDAbsence, Int32 IDEmployee, Int32 Period, DateTime BeginDate, DateTime? EndDate, AbsenceType AbsenceType, AbsenceStatus AbsenceStatus, List<Justification> Justifications, List<Notification> Notifications)
    {
        this.IDAbsence = IDAbsence;
        this.IDEmployee = IDEmployee;
        this.Period = Period;
        this.BeginDate = BeginDate;
        this.EndDate = EndDate;
        this.AbsenceType = AbsenceType;
        this.AbsenceStatus = AbsenceStatus;
        this.Justifications = Justifications;
        this.Notifications = Notifications;
    }
    }

[Serializable] 
    public class TimePeriod
    {
        public Int32 IDTimePeriod;
        public DateTime StartTime;
        public DateTime EndTime;

        public TimePeriod() { }

        public TimePeriod(Int32 IDTimePeriod, DateTime StartTime, DateTime EndTime)
        {
            this.IDTimePeriod = IDTimePeriod;
            this.StartTime = StartTime;
            this.EndTime = EndTime;
        }
    }
```

The `TimePeriod` primary key (`IDTimePeriod`) should be the reference for the foreign key Period in the Absence Table, but I can't create a foreign key for Period (yeah, the DB I'm working with is pretty confusing...).

This is my LINQ query:

```
   public static List<Tuple<Absence,TimePeriod>> GetAbsencesByEmployeeIDAndYear(Int32 employeeID, Int32 year) {

                List<Tuple<Absence,TimePeriod>> absences = dataContext.Absences.Join(dataContext.TimePeriods,
                                                           abs => abs.Period,
                                                           tps => tps.IDTimePeriod,
                                                           (abs, tps) => new Tuple<Absence, TimePeriod>(abs, tps))
                                                 .Where(abstps => abstps.Item1.Employee.IDEmployee == employeeID && abstps.Item2.StartTime.Year == year).ToList();

            return absences;
        }
```

And this is the error:

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Strangely, because I've looked up in the DB and there are entries of Absences for that Employee in 2015 with the respective TimePeriod. There are no cases  where Period does not found the respective IDTimePeriod.

What am I missing?

Comment: if this query is correct you will get the expected output

Comment: Are you sure, you initialize your dataContext?

Comment: Shouldn't `Employee.IDEmployee` just be `IDEmployee`?

Comment: Try replacing Where(abstps => abstps.Item1.Employee.IDEmployee == employeeID && abstps.Item2.StartTime.Year == year with Where(abstps =>  abstps.Item1 != null && abstps.Item1.Employee != null && abstps.Item1.Employee.IDEmployee == employeeID &&  && abstps.Item2 != null && abstps.Item2.StartTime.Year == year

Comment: Yes, I initialized the dataContext...  Artem That EmployeeID is not supposed to be there, I erased it, since it's the Employee class that has a list of Absences, so you have to get the employee before getting his ID. Ako I still get the error...

Comment: I managed to get it right

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try:

```
public static List<Tuple<Absence,TimePeriod>> GetAbsencesByEmployeeIDAndYear(Int32 employeeID, Int32 year) {

    List<Tuple<Absence,TimePeriod>> absences = dataContext.Absences.Join(dataContext.TimePeriods,
     abs => abs.Period,
     tps => tps.IDTimePeriod,
     (abs, tps) => new { abs, tps})
     .Where(x => x.abs.Employee.IDEmployee == employeeID && x.tps.StartTime.Year == year)
    .Select(t => new Tuple<Absence,TimePeriod>(t.abs, t.tps))
    .ToList();

    return absences;
}
```

Comment: Only parameterless constructors and initializers are supported in LINQ to Entities.

Comment: I managed to get it right... I had to switch between the to list and the select and expect an IEnumerable